# I can't acess CSS file from sub-sub-category

Tags: css

I can access this CSS stylesheet from sub-category (folder) by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
```

What can I do with sub-sub-category?

Comment: show the directory structure as well>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a base path to your assets folder, then create a tag

```
<base href="base_path_via_server_side" >
```

Comment: can you explain what this tag do?

Comment: ok imagine the scenario where you create a base_url link for each of your assets "<link href="BASE_URL/assets/shared/reset.css">    <img src="BASE_URL/images/image_one.png" alt="#" />"

<base href="BASE_URL" > cuts out the need for this..

Answer (score 3):

Instead of typing the path as:

```
../../css/style.css
```

type it like:

```
/css/style.css
```

Comment: Customize my answer to fit your needs. Judging by your example, try `/style.css`

Comment: Could you share your file structure. Or a sample site perhaps?

Comment: i have css at main directory /
and have sub category and i access the css by ../style.css
from this sub category i have a category that uses the sam css
but i can't access it even i type ../../ this happens -->
 i click an item it goes to `/categories/db/mysql.php` and when clicking again
/categories/db//db/mysql.php`

Answer (score 0):

To go to a parent directory up in hierarchy you need to add `../` Therefore to go to a parent of parent, you need to add `../../`

The shortcut method is to go to root directory which is done by adding `/` and then traversing the directory you want to access. This is a preferred and less error prone (soothes the eye) than above.